# Proving that a subspace of $\ell^1$ is bounded and closed, but not compact.

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

I am having some trouble with the following question:

> Let $\ell^1$ denote the space of all sequences $\{a_n\}_n$ of complex numbers such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\vert{a_n}\vert < \infty$, equipped with the metric $d(a,b) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\vert{a_n-b_n}\vert$.
>
> (i) Prove that $A=\left\{a \in \ell^1 : \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\vert{a_n}\vert \leq 1\right\}$ is bounded and closed, but not compact.

I believe I have the first two steps more or less correct but I am not sure how to demonstrate non-compactness.  I guess what is confusing me is working in this sequence space and I am having trouble visualizing what an open cover looks like for $\ell^1$ or what a sequence of sequences looks like so I can use tools like constructing finite open subcover or proving sequential compactness to demonstrate compactness.  In these sorts of problems is there a usual way of proving compactness?

Here is my attempt at proving the first two claims.

To prove boundedness we must show that $(\forall a \in A)(\exists x \in \ell^1)$ such that $d(a,x)\leq M$ for some $M \in \mathbb{R}$.

We choose an $x$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\vert{x_n}\vert = M$ for some $0\leq M < \infty$, then for arbitrary $a \in A$ we have

$$d(a,x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\vert{a_n-x_n}\vert \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\vert{a_n}\vert + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\vert{x_n}\vert \leq 1+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\vert{x_n}\vert = 1+M$$

Thus $d(a,x) \leq 1+M$ for all $a \in A$.

To prove that $A$ is closed we must show that if $p$ is a limit point of $A$ then $p \in A$.  To see this let $p$ be a limit point of $A$. Then $(\forall\varepsilon>0)$$(\exists q \in A)$ such that $d(p,q) < \varepsilon$.

With this in mind assume that $p \notin A$.  This implies that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\vert{p_n}\vert = M > 1$.

Therefore we have

$$\varepsilon > \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\vert{p_n-q_n}\vert \geq  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\big\vert\vert{p_n}\vert-\vert{q_n}\vert\big\vert \geq \left\vert\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\vert{p_n}\vert - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\vert{q_n}\vert\right\vert = \left\vert{M-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\vert{q_n}\vert}\right\vert$$

giving in the end

$$\left\vert{M-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\vert{q_n}\vert}\right\vert < \varepsilon$$

But this raises a contradiction since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\vert{q_n}\vert$ is at most $1$. For instance if $M= 3/2$ we have

$$1/2 \leq \left\vert{M-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\vert{q_n}\vert}\right\vert \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\vert{p_n-q_n}\vert < \varepsilon$$

which clearly does not hold for all $\varepsilon > 0$.

Any help on approaching compactness would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You use the wrong definition of limit point. Therefore your proof is flawed. $p$ is a limit point if for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $q\in A$ such that $d(p,q) < \varepsilon$. Thus, the $q$ depends on $\varepsilon$. The $q$ you use is actually equal to $p$ because $d(p,q)<\varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon > 0$ means $d(p,q) = 0$ and therefore $p=q$.

Comment: Ok I see what you're saying, my wording for $q$ and $\varepsilon$ was permutted.

Comment: However, your proof is not valid.

Comment: Do you see the mistake?

Comment: No I don't, I was looking it over but I don't see where I went wrong.

Comment: $q$ and thus $M$ depend on $\varepsilon$. So, it could be that $M$ is very close to $1$. Your mistake is that you leave $\varepsilon$ arbitrary. You have to fix it. I suggest $\varepsilon := \sum_n|p_n| - 1$. ;-)

Comment: Ahhh, ok that makes sense now. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A$ is compact, then every sequence in $A$ has a convergent subsequence. Consider the standard basis $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ for $\ell^1$ as a sequence. The distance between any two elements of this sequence is $2$, so no subsequence will be Cauchy.

Comment: If $c\notin\mathbb R$, $c\sqrt 2> 0$ does not make sense. Why don't you just choose $c=1$?

Comment: Ah, ok. But it should actually be $\le$ in $A$. Otherwise it wouldn't be closed, right? (and therefore not compact) I guess that's kind of a typo by OP. So, you can actually choose $c=1$.

Comment: @amsmath . Right. $A$ is  $not$ closed. Replace "$<$" by "$\leq$" in the def'n of $A$ and you will have a closed set. As you say. probably a typo.

Comment: Edited.${}{}{}$